# dplyr: Is it possible to return two columns in summarize using one function?

Tags: r, dplyr

Say I have a function that returns two scalars, and I want to use it with `summarize`, e.g.

```r
fn = function(x) {
  list(mean(x), sd(x))
}

iris %>%
  summarize(fn(Petal.Length)) # Error: Column `fn(Petal.Length)` must be length 1 (a summary value), not 2


iris %>% 
  summarize(c("a","b") := fn(Petal.Length)) 
# Error: The LHS of `:=` must be a string or a symbol Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

I tried both ways, but can't figure it out.

However, this can be done with `data.table`

```r
library(data.table)
iris1 = copy(iris)
setDT(iris1)[, fn(Petal.Length)]
```

Is there a way to do this in `dplyr`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can save them as a list in a column and then use `unnest_wider` to separate them in different columns.

```
fn = function(x) {
  list(mean = mean(x),sd = sd(x))
}

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

iris %>%
  summarise(temp = list(fn(Petal.Length))) %>% 
  unnest_wider(temp)

# A tibble: 1 x 2
#   mean    sd
#  <dbl> <dbl>
#1  3.76  1.77
```

Or `unnest_longer` to have them in separate rows

```
iris %>%
  summarise(temp = list(fn(Petal.Length))) %>% 
  unnest_longer(temp)

#   temp temp_id
#  <dbl> <chr>  
#1  3.76 mean   
#2  1.77 sd
```